# Huffman Tree and Three Ambiguous facts

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, computer-science, information-theory, coding-theory

I see three facts on [Huffman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) Algorithms:

**Two of them is True:**

**Fact A:** The average length of an **optimal** code is always at most $\lceil \log n \rceil$, where $n$ is the number of codewords.

**Fact B:** The average codeword length in Huffman's algorithm is $\Omega(\log n)$.

and one Fact that say this is **False**:

**Fact C:** The average codeword length in Huffman's algorithm is $O(\log n)$.

> Really I couldn't get the point, what is the difference among these
> three facts. Is there any example or simple intuitive idea about these
> three facts? (I means what is the role of "optimal" words in first
> fact, or what is difference among these three facts in very short sentence)

Answer (score 3):

First fact speaks about average **length** of **optimal** code, while second and third speaks about average **codeword length** of some specific (Huffman's) code.

Given probability distribution on $n$ symbols and some code $c$, average codeword length is just average length of words in code - $\frac{1}{n} \sum |c(i)|$ (expectation wrt uniform distribution), while average length is expectation wrt given probability distribution - $\sum |c(i)| \cdot p_i$.

The first fact, informally, says that if we need to transmit many symbols sampled from some distribution, we well need at most $\lceil \log n\rceil$ bits in average for each symbol if we use good code.

It's also known that Huffman's code is optimal. However, average codeword length can be significantly greater than average length - length of codes of rare symbols don't significantly affect average length, but they do affect average length as much as lengths of codes of frequent symbols.

Fact B says that Huffman's code definitely have "many" "long" codewords (so average length is quite large).

Fact C claims that all words in Huffman's code are "short", but it's not necessary true. For example, if we have symbols with probabilities $\frac{1}{2}$, $\frac{1}{4}$, $\frac{1}{8}$, ..., $\frac{1}{2^n}$, $\frac{1}{2^n}$ - for a total of $n + 1$ symbols - Huffman's code will assign them codewords with lengths $1$, $2$, $3$, ..., $n$, $n$ respectively - so average codeword length will be $\frac{\frac{n(n + 1)}{2} + n}{n + 1} \approx \frac{n}{2} \gg \log n$.

Average length of code will be $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{i}{2^n} + \frac{n}{2^n} = 2 - 2^{1 - n} = O(\log n)$.

Comment: Sorry, I for some reason thought it's about length according to generating distribution. Will fix it now.

Comment: Sorry, can you please specify example of what is needed? "Expectation wrt uniform distribution" in my text is just fancy way to name the sum written.